# Including Google Api Client library classes through set_include_path dynamically

Tags: php, path, include, set, google-api-client

I want to include the classes of "google-api-php-client" (and I manually uploaded to my hosting in a subfolder Blog) to use on my website, I'm trying to include it dynamically with "set_include_path" function. However when applying the require_once my code stops there so I failed to include them. I show the code I've been testing for this purpose:

Alternatively, you can Set the same ini directive dynamically in your code.
set_include_path (get_include_path () path_separator '/ path / to / google-api-php-client / src'..);

MY CODE:

```
// 1st try with the full path to the folder classes Google Api:
set_include_path (get_include_path (). path_separator. '/home/u140888/domains/segurosq.com/public_html/blog/google-api-php-client/src'))

// 2nd try with the route from the subfolder Blog to Google Api classes:
set_include_path (get_include_path () path_separator '/ blog / google-api-php-client / src'..);

// 3rd attempt the route from the folder with Google Api classes:
set_include_path (get_include_path () path_separator '/ google-api-php-client / src'..);

// This line require_once my code stops and you can not instantiate the class within Client.php because it has not been added successfully:
require_once 'Google / Client.php';
```

I tried this even directly in the include_path parameter settings PHP.ini into my cPanel hosting or hosting provider without success.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in /home/u140888/domains/segurosq.com/public_html/blog/ try this:

set_include_path ('/home/u140888/domains/segurosq.com/public_html/blog/google-api-php-client/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

require_once('google-api-php-client/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
...

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm good to go. The problem was that I wasn't using the correct version of Google Api's files for my version of PHP 5.2. Now I'm able to instanciate those classes seamlessly. Thanks for your help I really appreciated. :-)